# Edit Note in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Im trying to make editing note functionality in my notes app and stuck on this point. Can somebody help me with it? In this version of code I have error 'dispatch is not a function' in EDIT_NOTE reducer.
So, here is my:
Actions:

```
    import { ADD_NOTE, DELETE_NOTE, EDIT_NOTE } from './actionTypes'
    
    export const editNoteAction = (text, id) => ({
      type: EDIT_NOTE,
      payload: {
        id,
        text,
      },
    })
```

Reducer:

```
    import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
    import { ADD_NOTE, DELETE_NOTE, EDIT_NOTE } from './actionTypes'
    
    const date = new Date()
    
    export const initialState = {
      notes: [
        {
          id: nanoid(),
          text: '',
          date: '',
        },
      ],
    }
    
    export default function notes(state = initialState, { type, payload }) {
      console.log(type)
      switch (type) {
        case ADD_NOTE: {
          ...
        case DELETE_NOTE: {
          ...
        case EDIT_NOTE: {
          const editedNote = {
            text: payload.text,
            id: payload.id,
            date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
          }
          return {
            notes: state.notes.map((note) =>
              note.id === payload.id
                ? {
                    ...state,
                    notes: [...state.notes, editedNote],
                  }
                : state
            ),
          }
        }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

NoteList - the component where all notes are collected:

```
    const NoteList = ({
      Notes,
      addNoteAction,
      deleteNoteAction,
      editNoteAction,
    }) => {
      console.log(Notes)
      return (
        <div className={styles.notesList}>
          <AddNote handleAddNote={addNoteAction} />
          {Notes.map((note) => (
            <Note
              key={note.id}
              id={note.id}
              text={note.text}
              date={note.date}
              handleDeleteNote={deleteNoteAction}
              handleEditNote={editNoteAction}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      Notes: state.notes || [],
    })
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      addNoteAction: (text) => dispatch(addNoteAction(text)),
      deleteNoteAction: (id) => dispatch(deleteNoteAction(id)),
      editNoteAction: (id) => dispatch(editNoteAction(id)),
    })
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NoteList)
```

And Note component

```
    
    const Note = ({
      id,
      text,
      date,
      handleDeleteNote,
      handleEditNote,
      editNoteAction,
      Notes,
    }) => {
      const [animType, setAnimType] = useState(AnimationTypes.ANIM_TYPE_ADD)
    
      const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false)
      const handleToggleEdit = () => {
        if (!isEdit) {
          editNoteAction(text)
        }
        setIsEdit(!isEdit)
      }
    
      const [newText, setNewText] = useState('')
      const handleTextChange = (e) => {
        setNewText(e.target.value)
      }
    
      const onNoteSave = () => {
        handleToggleEdit()
        editNoteAction({
          id,
          date,
          text: newText,
        })
      }
    
      return (
        <div className={classnames(styles.note, styles[animType])}>
          {isEdit ? (
            <IsEditingNote
              formalClassName={styles.editNote}
              formalRef={noteTextareaRef}
              formalOnChange={handleTextChange}
              formalValue={newText}
            />
          ) : (
            <span className={styles.noteText}>{text}</span>
          )}
          <div className={styles.noteFooter}>
            <small>{date}</small>
            <div className={styles.footerIcons}>
              {!isEdit ? (
                <EditingIcon
                  formalClassName={styles.editIcon}
                  formalOnClick={handleToggleEdit}
                />
              ) : (
                <MdCheck
                  className={styles.deleteIcon}
                  size="1.4em"
                  onClick={onNoteSave}
                />
              )}
              <MdDeleteForever
                className={styles.deleteIcon}
                size="1.2em"
                onClick={() => {
                  setAnimType(AnimationTypes.ANIM_TYPE_DELETE)
                  setTimeout(() => handleDeleteNote(id), 500)
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      Notes: state.notes || [],
    })
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      editNoteAction: (editedNote) => dispatch(editNoteAction(editedNote)),
    })
    
    export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(Note)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where this error is coming from - but note that you don't need to pass all the XXXNoteAction functions as props to each component, since they're injected by Redux via your `mapDispatchToProps`. It's possible that removing this will remove the error (but I'm far from sure).

Comment: No, this does not work =(